# Nouveau drivers doesn't work on Ubuntu 20.04 with PRIME

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 20.04, nvidia-optimus, nouveau

I'm trying to use nouveau drivers in Ubuntu 20.04 with an nVidia Optimus card (GeForce GTX 1650).

This is the output of `inxi -G`:

```
Graphics:  Device-1: Intel UHD Graphics driver: i915 v: kernel 
           Device-2: NVIDIA driver: nouveau v: kernel 
           Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.8 driver: nouveau resolution: 1920x1080~60Hz 
           OpenGL: renderer: Mesa Intel UHD Graphics (CML GT2) v: 4.6 Mesa 20.0.8
```

When I run `DRI_PRIME=0 glxinfo | grep 'OpenGL renderer string'`:

```
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa Intel(R) UHD Graphics (CML GT2)
```

But if I use `DRI_PRIME=1`, then some libGL errors appears:

```
libGL error: failed to create dri screen
libGL error: failed to load driver: nouveau
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa Intel(R) UHD Graphics (CML GT2)
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need to install those drivers.

if you get rid of nouveau to use nvidia drivers:

https://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2015/fedora-nvidia-guide/

You need to use __GLX_VENDOR_LIBRARY_NAME=nvidia to force the driver:

```
$ inxi -G
Graphics:  Device-1: Intel UHD Graphics 620 driver: i915 v: kernel 
           Device-2: NVIDIA GP106 [GeForce GTX 1060 3GB] driver: nvidia v: 470.74 
           Device-3: Acer SunplusIT Integrated Camera type: USB driver: uvcvideo 
           Display: wayland server: X.Org 1.21.1.2 driver: loaded: nvidia resolution: 1920x1080~60Hz 
           OpenGL: renderer: Mesa Intel UHD Graphics 620 (KBL GT2) v: 4.6 Mesa 21.1.8 
$ DRI_PRIME=0 glxinfo | grep 'OpenGL renderer string'
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa Intel(R) UHD Graphics 620 (KBL GT2)
$ DRI_PRIME=1 glxinfo | grep 'OpenGL renderer string'
libGL error: failed to create dri screen
libGL error: failed to load driver: nouveau
OpenGL renderer string: llvmpipe (LLVM 12.0.1, 256 bits)
$ __GLX_VENDOR_LIBRARY_NAME=nvidia DRI_PRIME=1 glxinfo | grep 'OpenGL renderer string'
OpenGL renderer string: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060 3GB/PCIe/SSE2
```